# How to pass data to nested layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Lets say i want to extend my layout in my .NET MVC 4 application. So i have created a nested layout in a quite simple way:

**_Root.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

**_productView.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Layouts/_Root.cshtml";
}
```

**_productListView.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Layouts/_Root.cshtml";
}
```

Now i get a product from my database and want to set the title of the product catagory in _productView.cshtml. For example lets say i want a title that is electronics. I want to do this when i get the product from the database before i make a viewmodel of it and return a view in my controller:

**ProductController**

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) {
        var product= repository.GetById(new Guid(id));

        if(product== null) {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
        }

        var model = Mapper.Map<IProduct, ProductViewModel>(product);

        return View(model);
    }
```

What i want to do is get the products type from the product and use it in the _productView.cshtml but i know it can´t be done with viewbag. So how can i do this?

Regards Jonathan

**UPDATE**
I will extend the example:

If i in my controller do this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) {
        var product= repository.GetById(new Guid(id));

        if(product== null) {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
        }
                    Viewbag.ProductType = product.productType;

        var model = Mapper.Map<IProduct, productViewModel>(product);

        return View(model);
    }
```

And then in my productView.cshtml

**_productView.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Layouts/_Root.cshtml";
}
@Viewbag.productType
```

I will get a compile error telling me that viewbag does not exist in the current context.

My view for the product looks like this:

```
@model producttest.product.Web.ProductViewModel

@{
Layout = "~/Layouts/_productView.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = @Model.Name;

}


<h1>@Model.Name)</h1>
<section>
<h2>@Model.Description, @Model.Price</h2>
<p>
    @Model.ImageUrl<br />
</p>
</section>
```

This is what i try to achive, but i have read that viewbag can´t be used this way, how can i do it in another way?

UPDATE 2:

The Viewbag was just a typo, here is the actual code:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Row 3:      
Row 4:  }
Row 5:  @ViewBag.productType;
```

Comment: Needs to be @ViewBag.productType

Comment: It should be ViewBag, as opposed to viewbag

Comment: @David Hirst Yeah sorry thats a typo, updated the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out! Since i used a nested layout structure i moved my layouts from the View folder, to a seperate folder named "Layouts". In every "Views" folder there is a Web.config that reference namespaces, this file was missing since i copied my layouts to another folder.

thanks to @JMK and @David Hirst for the help which led me this way!

Regard Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is that you do not need to have this in your views

```
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
```

This is only required in your layout. Remember that @RenderBody is the place holder for your View Markup.

I would recommend you strongly type your views to use a ViewModel, a POCO that represents the data you wish to pass to the view. Some people just pass the object they are working with and this is works but sometimes the object you work with and the what you want to represent on your view can be different so it makes more sense to have separate ViewModels.

You can mark your views with this to select the strongly typed object you want.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```

You can then access the properties directly in your view as such

```
@Model.MyProperty
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i think you missunderstand the question. I am new to MVC but i know how to use views. What i am asking is how can i set viewbag.ProductCatagory and then render it in the _productView layout, not how to render a view. I know i cant do that with a viewbag since and the result of doing that will give me a compile error som what i ask for is a solution to be able to take data from my controller (suggestion) and display it in a parrent layout. But one lesson learned, the @renderbody i redundant! Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan Why would that give you an error? Can you post your actual code?

Comment: @JMK I extended the example. Thx for the reply!

Comment: If you set the value to ViewBag.ProductType in your action method (note the case!) then on your view it should be @ViewBag.ProductType. Your compile error is because you have not used the correct case on ViewBag. I'm not quite sure why you are trying to use nested layouts however.

Comment: @David Hirst The nested layouts is for a specific case, this is just an example. I upated the question with the error i get when i follow your solution. thanks for your replys!